# How can I modify an account from "Accounts you've added" using Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

How can I modify an account from "Accounts you've added" using Outlook.com?

When I try to change the SMP server of OVH, the Outlook.com replies:

> It looks like you already added this account. Please check your account info and try again.